# Python3 2-d array copy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

```
b = [[1,1],[1,0]]
a = [[0]*2]*2
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]
print(a)
print(b)
```

and the outputs are:

```
[[1,1],[1,0]]
[[1,0],[1,0]]
```

I don't know where going wrong. Isn't the a should be the exact same as the b?

Comment: why do you want to copy an array using loops ? There are shorter and faster ways.

Comment: @miradulo thank you!
@Manish Saraswat I know, but I just wanna know what is wrong with `a = [[0]*2]*2`

Comment: @Victor.L No problem! Feel free to mark your question as a duplicate of that one - it doesn't negatively affect you, and will help others find their way to that answer. Thanks!